Proxmox Unable to Connect to TrueNAS iSCSI Target Using CHAP Authentication
Problem Description:
I am experiencing persistent issues connecting my Proxmox server to a TrueNAS iSCSI target using CHAP authentication. Despite configuring both TrueNAS and Proxmox according to the documentation, the connection fails with an authentication error.
Environment Details:

Proxmox Version: Proxmox VE 7.x
TrueNAS Version: TrueNAS Scale (latest stable version)
Network Configuration:

Proxmox IP: 192.168.2.100
TrueNAS IP: 192.168.2.105
iSCSI Port: 3260



Error Message:
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
root@pve:~# iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1 -p 192.168.2.105 --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1, portal: 192.168.2.105,3260]
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (24 - iSCSI login failed due to authorization failure)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals

TrueNAS Configuration:

Global Configuration:

Base Name: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl
iSCSI listen port: 3260


Portals:

Portal Group ID: 1
Listen: 0.0.0.0:3260
Discovery Auth Method: CHAP
Discovery Auth Group: 1


Initiators Groups:

Group ID: 1
Initiators: Allow all initiators


Authorized Access:

Group ID: 1
User: cassandra
Peer User: (if applicable)
Ensure the password for the cassandra user is correctly set.


Targets:

Target Name: cassandra-db1
Portal Group ID: 1 (cassandra-db1)
Initiator Group ID: 1 (ALL Initiators Allowed)
Authentication Method: CHAP
Authentication Group Number: 1


Extents:

Extent Name: cassandra-db1
Device/File: zvol/oasis/cassandra-db1
Ensure it is enabled and properly configured.


Associated Targets:

Target: cassandra-db1
LUN ID: 0
Extent: cassandra-db1



Proxmox Configuration:

Storage Configuration:

Edit /etc/pve/storage.cfg to include the iSCSI storage entry with CHAP credentials:
iscsi: iscsi-cassandra-db1
    portal 192.168.2.105
    target iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1
    content none
    nodes pve
    username cassandra
    password your_password




iSCSI Initiator Settings:

Use the following commands to update the iSCSI initiator settings on Proxmox:
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1 -p 192.168.2.105 --op update -n node.session.auth.authmethod -v CHAP
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1 -p 192.168.2.105 --op update -n node.session.auth.username -v cassandra
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1 -p 192.168.2.105 --op update -n node.session.auth.password -v your_password
iscsiadm -m node -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1 -p 192.168.2.105 --login




Verify iSCSI Initiator Name:

Ensure the initiator name on Proxmox matches what is allowed on TrueNAS:
cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi


The content should be:
InitiatorName=iqn.1993-08.org.debian:01:f332ba64e9ee







Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified CHAP credentials on TrueNAS and Proxmox.
Ensured the iSCSI initiator name matches on both TrueNAS and Proxmox.
Confirmed network connectivity between Proxmox and TrueNAS using nc -zv 192.168.2.105 3260.
Restarted the iSCSI service on TrueNAS (service ctld restart).
Reviewed Proxmox logs for detailed errors using journalctl -xe | grep iscsi and dmesg | grep iscsi.

Logs:

Proxmox Logs:
May 28 01:06:45 pve iscsid[3336856]: Could not set session428 priority. READ/WRITE throughout and latency could be affected.
May 28 01:06:45 pve iscsid[3336856]: Login failed to authenticate with target iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1
May 28 01:06:45 pve iscsid[3336856]: session 428 login rejected: Initiator failed authentication with target
May 28 01:06:45 pve iscsid[3336856]: Connection428:0 to [target: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:cassandra-db1, portal: 192.168.2.105,3260] through [iface: default] is shutdown.



Request for Help:
Despite following the steps mentioned, I am still unable to connect to the iSCSI target from Proxmox. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing the authentication failure would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
If there are any specific details or configurations that I need to check, please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

In storage config it should be like below, if you define username and password in  /etc/pve/storage.cfg  for iscsi storage type it will not work
root@pve-node01:~# cat /etc/pve/storage.cfg 
scsi: ssd-storage
    portal 192.168.1.3
    target iqn.2024-08.org.example:proxmox-target-ssd-storage
    content none


And then authentication parameters should be included in /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf if used
Example
node.session.auth.authmethod = CHAP
node.session.auth.username = username
node.session.auth.password = password

